# How to Change Font of Paragraph to Specific Font CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, web

I need to change the font of a paragraph to a specific font, my font is in a ttf file.Also everything is local (downloaded unto my website folder). here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Unwritten</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="cloak.png">
    <style>
        body {
            margin-bottom: 200%;
            background-image: url("site.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        } 

        #download_button { 
            position:absolute;
            transition: .5s ease;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%; 
            background-color: transparent;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            border: none;
            cursor:pointer;
            overflow: hidden;
            outline:none; 
            font: "font.ttf";
        } 
    </style>
</head> 
<body>  
    <header> 
        <p class="buttons">This is in a font.<p>
    </header> 
    <section>   

    </section> 
    <footer> 
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: .buttons {font-family: yourFont;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to import your font via CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontName';
  src: url('fontname.eot');
  src: url('fontname?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fontname.svg#Locaweb-Icons') format('svg'),
    url('fontname.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then, you may use it:

```
p.buttons {
    font-family: 'FontName';
}
```